# Returning a list of data.tables from sapply

Tags: r, data.table, sapply

I have an interesting problem.  I have some unknown number of ginormous tables, but at least 2.  They have the same schema and I want to pull subsets from each one and create a specialized cross join so I can combine various parts.

So start with a simple example of 2 data.table objects:

```
DT1 <- data.table(A = rep(1:2, each = 2), B = rep(1:2, 2), C = sample(4))
DT2 <- data.table(A = rep(1:2, 2), B = sample(4), C = rep(1:2, each = 2))

> DT1
A B C
1 1 2
1 2 3
2 1 1
2 2 4

> DT2
A B C
1 2 1
2 1 1
1 3 2
2 4 2
```

Because I ultimately don't know how many tables I will have to subset, I create a list and pass it to a function to do the subsetting using sapply:

```
tables = list(DT1, DT2)
foo <- function(dt, value) {
  result <- dt[A == value,]
  return(result)
}

combined <- sapply(tables, foo, value = 1)
```

The combined result, however, is a mismosh of vectors with no schema.  What I would like to get back is a list of data.tables.  The foo function returns a data.table but the result gets scrambled in the sapply.  How do I modify the code to perform an operation similar to this?

```
combined <- list(DT1[A == 1,], DT2[A == 1])
```

Resulting in a list of data.tables

```
> combined
[[1]]
   A B C
1: 1 1 2
2: 1 2 3

[[2]]
   A B C
1: 1 2 1
2: 1 3 2
```

TIA as always.

Comment: `sapply` tries to simplify the result. You need to use `lapply` if you want a list as result.

Comment: File this one under doh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach, using `dplyr` and `lapply`, is below.  Extending this work can make it more dynamic.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)

DT1 <- data.table(A = rep(1:2, each = 2), B = rep(1:2, 2), C = sample(4))
DT2 <- data.table(A = rep(1:2, 2), B = sample(4), C = rep(1:2, each = 2))
DT3 <- data.table(A = rep(1:2, each = 2), B = sample(4), C = rep(1:2, times = 2))
DT4 <- data.table(A = rep(1:2, 2), B = sample(4), C = rep(1:2, each = 2))

# View the data.tables
list(DT1, DT2, DT3, DT4)
# [[1]]
#    A B C
# 1: 1 1 4
# 2: 1 2 3
# 3: 2 1 1
# 4: 2 2 2
# 
# [[2]]
#    A B C
# 1: 1 3 1
# 2: 2 2 1
# 3: 1 4 2
# 4: 2 1 2
# 
# [[3]]
#    A B C
# 1: 1 3 1
# 2: 1 4 2
# 3: 2 1 1
# 4: 2 2 2
# 
# [[4]]
#    A B C
# 1: 1 4 1
# 2: 2 1 1
# 3: 1 3 2
# 4: 2 2 2
# 

# Get a List of data.tables For A == 1
lapply(list(DT1, DT2, DT3, DT4),
       function(.data, ...) { as.data.table(dplyr::filter_(.data, ...)) },
       ~ A == 1)
# [[1]]
#    A B C
# 1: 1 1 4
# 2: 1 2 3
# 
# [[2]]
#    A B C
# 1: 1 3 1
# 2: 1 4 2
# 
# [[3]]
#    A B C
# 1: 1 3 1
# 2: 1 4 2
# 
# [[4]]
#    A B C
# 1: 1 4 1
# 2: 1 3 2
# 

# Get a List of data.tables For A == 2
lapply(list(DT1, DT2, DT3, DT4),
       function(.data, ...) { as.data.table(dplyr::filter_(.data, ...)) },
       ~ A == 2)
# [[1]]
#    A B C
# 1: 2 1 1
# 2: 2 2 2
# 
# [[2]]
#    A B C
# 1: 2 2 1
# 2: 2 1 2
# 
# [[3]]
#    A B C
# 1: 2 1 1
# 2: 2 2 2
# 
# [[4]]
#    A B C
# 1: 2 1 1
# 2: 2 2 2
#
```

Extending the this method to allow for more complex filtering conditions is easy.  All you need to do is add the conditions to within the `lapply` call.

```
# Get a list of data.tables for A == 2 and B == 1
lapply(list(DT1, DT2, DT3, DT4),
       function(.data, ...) { as.data.table(dplyr::filter_(.data, ...)) },
       ~ A == 2, ~ B == 1)
# [[1]]
#    A B C
# 1: 2 1 1
# 
# [[2]]
#    A B C
# 1: 2 1 2
# 
# [[3]]
#    A B C
# 1: 2 1 1
# 
# [[4]]
#    A B C
# 1: 2 1 1
#
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo <- function(dt, value) {
  result <- dt[A == value,]
  return(result)
}

combined <- lapply(tables, foo, value = 1)
```

Comment: No, use `split`. See `?split`.